# Как можно объединить 3 картинки в одном блоке?

Tags: html, css

Как можно объединить 3-4 картинки в одном блоке?
Объединить в фотошопе их нельзя ибо каждую картинку нужно сделать ссылкой!
Что-то вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал просто поставить каждому z-index, но их нужно наклонить.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать такой вариант

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/PsIZdRn.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block .item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block .item img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) skewX(10deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.block .item:hover {
  transform: skewX(-10deg) scale(1.15);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hLy4Y8a.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oLkSSdv.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/85FVFSL.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ccvXg55.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нареж в фотошопе и отдельно 4 картинки ставь рядом .